# Javascript Share Bar URL Modification Issues

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm having a hard time getting my share bar on the left hand side of the following page to work properly:

https://www.tisaneteas.com/blog/understanding-how-the-ph-scale-works/

There's a JS file called social-share-kit-post.js that has the following code:

```
function getUrl(options, network, el) {
    var url, dataOpts = getDataOpts(options, network, el),
        shareUrl = getShareUrl(options, network, el, dataOpts),
        title = typeof dataOpts['title'] !== 'undefined' ? dataOpts['title'] : getTitle(network),
        text = typeof dataOpts['text'] !== 'undefined' ? dataOpts['text'] : getText(network),
        image = dataOpts['image'] ? dataOpts['image'] : getMetaContent('og:image'),
        via = typeof dataOpts['via'] !== 'undefined' ? dataOpts['via'] : getMetaContent('twitter:site'),
        paramsObj = {
            shareUrl: shareUrl,
            title: title,
            text: text,
            image: image,
            via: via,
            options: options,
            shareUrlEncoded: function () {
                return encodeURIComponent(this.shareUrl);
            }
        };
```

I'm trying to replace the URL with a Bitly URL so that I can track the clicks and shares on Bitly. Furthermore, when people share content, a Bitly link is shorter as titles of articles can get extremely long.

Please let me know if you can help! The Bitly link from a wordpress plugin is being echo'd via SHORTLINK to the page next to "BACK TO ALL POSTS".

HERE'S A PHOTO: http://www.tisaneteas.com/link.jpg

Thanks,
Stephen